# Problem with setting Browsing Path in Delphi option page

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

I have a problem with setting Browsing Path in Delphi 2009:

When I install a new component, I add DCU path to Delphi's Library Path, and source path to Delphi's Browsing Path. The application compiles fine, but holding Ctrl and clicking on any of the unit names for that component does not open the source file!

It seems the only way to make it work is to add source path to Library Path, but this means I have to compile all the units belonging to third-party components every time I build my project!

This problem does not exist for Delphi's standard units, or even JCL and JVCL units which are installed by JCL\JVCL installer, and their source paths are added to Browsing Path.

Is this a bug, or it is me doing something wrong?

Regards

Comment: I noticed something similar to this the other day.  I didn't get very far in determining if it was a bug or something wrong on my part.  Seeing you question here makes me think it is a bug or just different then expected (that is a bug too, right?)  I'll try it again and see what I come up with.

Comment: If it is a bug I hope they fix it in Update 3, which is due any day now.

Comment: Thanks Jim!

I remember a few months ago when I encountered this problem the first time, I tried to check behavior of Delphi IDE when holding Ctrl and clicking on one of those units, with SysInternals Process Monitor; and there was no record of querying the paths I added to Browsing Path!
But if it is a bug, then how can JVCL installer add its paths to Browsing Path, and it works just fine?!

Comment: The process explorer behaviour makes it sound like the issue is the IDE not looking, rather than the path being incorrect. (To state the bleeding obvious.) Is the behaviour any better after doing a build rather than a compile? I know that's my usual solution to source not being found by the IDE.

Comment: @Richard:
For me rebuilding the source code or restarting the IDE had no effect on this problem, and the problem still exists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was struggling with this problem for a long time. Changing REFERENCEINFO in package settings from "none" to "definitions only" did the trick. Hope this will help you also.

Comment: Thank you! That was the trick. It seems by default "Symbol Reference Info" is set to "Reference Info" by Delphi, and it works fine, but some vendors (e.g. Devart) change this setting for their packages to None, and this causes this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are any of these units listed in the .dpr ? Units there with a wrong path can cause pretty funky behaviour.

Comment: No. This is not related to a particular 3rd party component, I have this problem with all 3rd party components except JCL and JVCL which have their own installers. 
While I was investigating this, none of those units were used in project DPR file.
Regards

Answer (score 1):

Setting "Symbol Reference Info" to "Reference Info" does indeed fix the issue with Browsing Path.

But at least for Delphi XE the change has to be made in "Build Configuration -> Base" for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I would ensure the dcu's were compiled with debugging turned on. If this is a third party component and the source is provided with it this is usually the case but not always.

Comment: Of course source is provided with the component; otherwise, setting Browsing Path is meaningless!
Also, DCUs are compiled with debug information.