# Browse path / click-though issue

Tags: ide, delphi-2007

I have Raize 3.0 installed in D2007. For whatever reason, I can't seem to get the Ctr-click to work for loading up it's units, even though that feature works fine on all my other Delphi and Third-Party components.

Here's what I have for Raize on the Library Path:

```
$(ProgramFiles)\Raize\RC3\Lib6  
$(ProgramFiles)\Raize\RC3\Source
```

...and the Browsing Path:

```
$(ProgramFiles)\Raize\RC3\Source
```

Lib6 contains `*.dcu` and `*.dfm` files, and Source contains, obviously, the source code.  Adding Lib6 to the Browsing path doesn't seem to affect things one way or the other.

I don't get why this Ctrl-click unit-loading feature isn't working, just for this one component.  Any ideas what I may be missing?

Answer (score 0):

For lib path you generally don't need source files.  I use:

> C:\Program Files\Raize\RC4\Lib\BDS2007

For browsing path you need to specify the language directory, e.g.:

> C:\Program Files\Raize\RC4\Source\Lang\English

If this doesn't fix it, does your unit compile without errors?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need Source path in your Library path. Lib6 should be added to Library Path, and Source to Browsing Path.

If you do so, and it still doesn't work, then you have a similar problem with me:

[Problem with setting Browsing Path in Delphi option page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782341/problem-with-setting-browsing-path-in-delphi-option-page)